# On click on pinned icon of windows taskbar is redirecting to the "chrome://extensions" instead of opening app window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on the chrome extension, when I click on the pinned extension of the windows taskbar it should open the app window but it's redirecting to the chrome://extensions.

"manifest_version": 2
[image]

Comment: https://crbug.com/800432

Comment: Is there any way that we can override it?